# generate labels on top of image by code and non uniform locations

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, label

I am new to WPF.. I am trying to rewrite an application which i previously did using winforms. It is essentially an image of musical instrument (plucked string) which shows labels on each note place and ability to play it.

My questions is: I made a grid and I inserted a resource image the first row, spanning 3 coloumns. now i need to place multiple labels on this image, each label corresponds to a particular musical note. how do i place labels on an image .. please see these two pictures

This is my current WPF layout

[image: this is my current WPF layout]

This is how i did it in winforms

[image: this is how i did it in winforms]

And is it possible to generate multiple labels by code to be like the 2nd picture?

Notice that those labels will be shown while playing a song. Each label will correspond to a particular musical note

Comment: Canvas will suit the task better than Grid - you can add Labels as Canvas children and assign them fixed coordinates - very similar to winforms

Comment: thank you form quick reply.. the reason i used a grid is that i wanted to add some resizing restrictions on my window.. min max height and width and also to keep aspect ration.. i m still trying to find a good way to do this.. but i m not sure if i need the grid anymore to do this

Comment: btw,, my application will include more control below the image. such as buttons and combobox and textboxes.. put i m not showing them here.

Comment: You can easily layer controls over one another. Transparent background works well in wpf, much more practical than winforms. So you can have the textboxes and stuff in a layer above others.

Comment: For the label things, think in terms of a usercontrol. You can put a textblock in there for the letters or an itemscontrol with a horizontal stackpanel as itemscontainer. The labels can be presented using an itemscontrol with a canvas in it. Bind a collection and template each into a label/usercontrol. The itempresenter can bind canvas.left and canvas.top to properties from the viewmodel. You can calculate these.

Comment: i m trying now both approaches. i m inserting a canvas inside a grid area and i will see if i can adjust the positions of my labels.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to combine the canvas and the layout control of your choice. In this example i've used the dock panel.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="80" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Margin="5">Click me</Button>
            <Button Margin="5">Click me</Button>
            <Button Margin="5">Click me</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas x:Name="FretLayoutCanvas">
            <Button Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="15" >Fret 1</Button>
            <Button Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="55" >Fret 2</Button>
        </Canvas>
</DockPanel>
```

This will look something like this:

[image: Sample layout]

In the code behind add your controls to the FretLayoutCanvas and calculate appropriate Left and Top for each one.

Comment: the problem i have now.. even though every thing in my application can adopt to resizing.. the labels on the canvas inside a grid location will lose there location when resizing the window ( as i expected).

Comment: i m trying to find a way to make the labels stick to thier positions when the window resized.. can i relate a label location to a particular image pixel ?

Comment: Look into the Window Resizing event - You will have to trigger your layout logic there again. Might be worth investigating a proper custom control for this instead.